# List all the months using oracle sql 

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys, is there any better way to list all the months other than this:

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date('01/01/1000', 'DD/MM/RRRR'), ind.l-1), 'MONTH') as month_descr,
       ind.l as month_ind
  from dual descr,
       (select l
          from (select level l 
                  from dual 
                connect by level <= 12
               )
       ) ind
order by 2;
```

ANSWER:

```
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE, (LEVEL-1 )),'MONTH') as months 
  FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1
```

**ONE MORE QUESTION SEE BELOW**

Also I want to list the previous two years including the current year.  I wrote this sql query.  Let me know if there is anything better.

```
select extract(year from sysdate) - (level-1) as years 
  from dual 
connect by level <=3 
order by years
```

Comment: @ksogor and @Rob kindly look at the another question added above.

Comment: That second query is good enough.

Comment: As an aside RRRR doesn't make sense. Although Oracle doesn't error out  it's confusing.

Comment: @Stephanie RRRR - other person ?

Comment: Not sure what "Other Person" means. But... You show the picture format as 'DD/MM/RRRR'. Oracle uses two R's to do some clever tricks to avoid Y2K issues. But if you don't have a two digit date, you don't need that clever math YYYY is YYYY you don't need to guess at the proper century. 'DD/MM/RR' makes sense. You're asking oracle to guess at the century in an intelligent way. 'DD/MM/YYYY' makes sense because you know the exact century.  'DD/MM/RRRR' makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup.

1:

```
SELECT * FROM WWV_FLOW_MONTHS_MONTH;
```

2: (**UPD**:)

```
WITH MONTH_COUNTER AS (
  SELECT LEVEL-1 AS ID 
  FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
) 
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1000', 'DD/MM/RRRR'), ID),'MONTH') FROM MONTH_COUNTER;
```

Comment: @ksogor it says table or view does not exist.

Comment: You didn't write anything about your db version. It works for me.

Comment: Version of your "oracle sql"?

Comment: Just show answer from this sql query: `select * from v$version;`

Comment: wwv_flow_months_month requires APEX to be installed: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11947/priv_public.htm#HTMDB25949

Answer (score 14):

Not better, but just a bit cleaner:

```
SQL>  select to_char(date '2000-12-01' + numtoyminterval(level,'month'),'MONTH') as month
  2     from dual
  3  connect by level <= 12
  4  /

MONTH
---------
JANUARY
FEBRUARY
MARCH
APRIL
MAY
JUNE
JULY
AUGUST
SEPTEMBER
OCTOBER
NOVEMBER
DECEMBER

12 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 6):

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), level - 1), 'MONTH') months
  from dual
connect by level <= 12;
```

Returns:

```
MONTHS
--------------------
JANUARY
FEBRUARY
MARCH
APRIL
MAY
JUNE
JULY
AUGUST
SEPTEMBER
OCTOBER
NOVEMBER
DECEMBER

12 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT to_char(to_date( level,'mm'), 'MONTH') Months FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=12;
```

Regards,
Prasant Sutaria

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(rownum||'-'||rownum||'-'||'2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'Month') 
 FROM    all_objects 
 WHERE rownum < 13
```